# Is it possible to use Typescript union to specify field options

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a type which can accept any one of 2 options like this

```
  type Result = string | number

  type ValueData = {
     data: Result
  } 
  
 const valueDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     data: {
       type: Result
      }
  );
```

Is this legal?

Comment: I don't know anything about mongodb or mongoose but that code isn't legal unless you have a *value* named `Result` in scope.  If you provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE I could tell you more.  Otherwise maybe someone with mongodb/mongoose knowledge will come along and elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

The unique thing that you should take care of is the behavior in each of your options.

For example, you can use a `typeof` (as well as "is..." methods like isNaN, isArray, etc.) to verify the parameter to avoid unexpected behavior.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

Comment: Are you sure?  Unless there is a *value* named `Result` in scope, the code in the question will fail to compile.

Comment: I know Typescript supports it, but it Mongodb that I am unsure about

Comment: It's not possible. I create a simple Mongoose project and it was not accepted by the Mongoose schema

Comment: Uh, that's true, @jcalz.
I thought that the type as an argument was an example and I answered only as if it were about establishing a type in the data passed into the schema.
Now I don't understand the point of the question, if it is about _only_ two possible options you can use an `enum`, otherwise, what are you trying exactly to do, @BreenDeen?

Comment: I was trying to provide a value that could be provided to the model for which I have no control which could come in as a string or number. However, I decided to use a different solution for that. Thank you for your response.